# Can I place the composer.json file for my project not on the root directory?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I am implementing a project that I want to share via Packagist. Usually, the `composer.json` file would be in the project root directory, but I want to have all the composer-related files and directories under the subdirectory `/private/composer`. After moving `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and `vendor`, Packagist is not able to find the `composer.json` on my remote repository, so my project will not auto-update anymore.

Is it possible to do what I want and still have Packagist auto-updating the project?

The project structure I want to achieve is like this:

```
.
├── .editorconfig
├── .git
│   ├── branches
│   ...
├── .gitignore
├── .htaccess
├── license.txt
├── private
│   ├── composer
│   │   ├── composer.json
│   │   ├── composer.lock
│   │   └── vendor
│   │       ├── autoload.php
│   │       ...
│   ├── npm
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── package-lock.json
│   │   └── node_modules
│   │       ...
├── public
│   └── index.php
└── readme.md
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No, it is not possible](https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/472).

Moreover, even if it was possible, I would not recommend it - this is unusual configuration and it would only confuse users of your package.

Comment: I think it is more confusing to have lots of configuration files on your project root directory. If I wanted to have this project on several package managers it would be a mess. I will post on that issue asking for supporting this. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the given file structure contain "lots of configuration files"? And why is that confusing?

Comment: @NicoHaase A regular project may contain several files of different kind in its root directory. For example, I have a readme.md, a license.txt, a .gitignore, an .editorconfig, a .htaccess, a .git subdirectory and my IDE configuration subdirectory. I prefer not to add more files to this mess. Also, I may like to add my project to other package managers now or in the future, so I want to keep things organized.

Using composer will add a composer.json, a composer.lock and a vendor directory: I think it will be interesting to store them into a "composer" subdirectory, somewhere in my project.